# Reactjs: In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) [handling-events documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html), and I came across this:

> **In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default**. If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.

What I understand from this quotation is that `this` doesn't designate the current instantiation in every class methods.

However, if I consider the code below, the method `editState` can access the property `state` of the extended class `Parent` through `this`. Which would make false the previous quotation, as `this` is bound to all the class mehtods.

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.state = false;
  }
  
  setState(newState) {
    this.state = newState;
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  editState() {
    this.setState(true);
  }
}

let c = new Child;
c.editState();
console.log(c.state);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Not bound by default mean that when you give your method as a callback for an event (`onClick={this.editState}` for example) the `onClick` event bind your function with another context, except if you explicitely bind your method with the right context before (`this.editState = this.editState.bind(this)` in the constructor or use arrow function).
So it's normally that when you call editState yourself, you can access to `this`.

Comment: `event bind your function with another context` what do you mean by this

Comment: Suggestions: Change your title to a question (currently it's a statement)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When a function is used as an event handler, its '*this*' is set to the element the event fired from.
[As a DOM event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 2):

I think the React documentation might be misleading.  The React component below `MyClass` is a derived class (aka child class) of `React.Component`.  The `constructor` method is a special method within javascript ES6 which is used for creating and initializing an object created with a class.  React uses the constructor to pass `props` to the component when the object is created.  Base classes (aka parent classes) are created bound to their own `this`, but the derived classes do not have their own `this` by default.  The derived class must call super(props) which binds the `this` from the base class down into the derived class.

```
class MyClass extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant information from the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) provided by user376830's answer.  This is straight from the javascript documentation.

## Class context

The behavior of `this` in classes and functions is similar, since classes are functions under the hood. But there are some differences and caveats.

Within a class constructor, `this` is a regular object. All non-static methods within the class are added to the prototype of `this`:

```
class Example {
    constructor() {
      const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
      console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto));
    }
    first(){}
    second(){}
    static third(){}
}

 new Example(); // ['constructor', 'first', 'second']
```

*Note: Static methods are not properties of `this`. They are properties of the class itself.*

## Derived classes

Unlike base class constructors, derived constructors have no initial `this` binding. Calling  `super()` creates a `this` binding within the constructor and essentially has the effect of evaluating the following line of code, where Base is the inherited class:

`this = new Base();`

*Warning: Referring to this before calling `super()` will throw an error.*

Derived classes must not return before calling `super()`, unless they return an `Object` or have no constructor at all.

```
class Base {}
    class Good extends Base {}
    class AlsoGood extends Base {
    constructor() {
        return {a: 5};
    } 
 }

class Bad extends Base {
    constructor() {}
}

new Good();
new AlsoGood();
new Bad(); // ReferenceError
```

Answer (score 0):

William's answer is the most correct after following the link he provided. I'm just posting this to save anybody the time. It is quite a read. Regarding this question when you pass a function as a variable, you need to be careful about the context it is going to be used in.

From my understanding, when a method is fired from a class it's 'this' gets bound to the class object. When it is fired from an event handler it's 'this' gets bound to the button element that fired the event. Since button elements aren't javascript objects, they do not have a 'this' property hence the undefined value.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31967082)