# What does react 18 docs mean by "In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please note this question is not talking about previous versions of react as in this 2017 question [Reactjs: In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275742/reactjs-in-javascript-class-methods-are-not-bound-by-default)

---

In reactjs docs on [Handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), they mention the following for [this example](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/xEmzGg?editors=0010)

> **In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default**. If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.

I think the bold statement is technically incorrect. Consider the following example:

```js
class component2 {
  prop = 3;
  foo() {
    console.log(this.prop);
  }
}
var obj = new component2();
obj.foo();
```

```html
<button id="one">Print prop</button>
```

As you can see I didn't have to bind `this`. This contradicts react18 documentation and also contradicts [react2017 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48701739/3429430)

Comment: Your example is wrong. It calls the method *on the object instance*. The quote refers to passing them as references. [See here](https://jsbin.com/royoyusivi/1/edit?html,js,console,output). This is what you'd get if you did `<button onClick={obj.foo}>` in React. Rather than the *correct* `this`-preserving `<button onClick={() => obj.foo()}>` or `<button onClick={obj.foo.bind(obj)}>` (I prefer the former for aesthetic reasons but both are essentially equivalent)

Comment: Interesting! the marked duplicates are not about react js. They don't explain why is `this` not bound by default in react js, as I have already proved that (contrary to react docs) In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default.

Comment: "*why is this not bound by default in react js,*" React is not a separate language, or environment, or runtime or anything. It's a plain library that works by the normal JS rules.

Comment: https://codepen.io/tushar8/pen/abGBJBq?editors=0011 This is what actually happens

Comment: Notice, `obj.bar()` is not called on click. But `bar` is.

Comment: `this` will not be the global object, but `undefined` because ES6 classes run in strict mode. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#strict_mode_for_classes

Comment: @VLAZ react is js but we are dealing with babel and JSX here. From your example it seems like react is converting `onClick` to `addEventListener("click")` behind the scenes, in which case yes `this` should work as you say. But react docs statement `In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default` is a general statement about js classes not about event listeners.

Comment: When they say React methods are not bound by default, they mean - If you call `bar` somewhere else it would have no idea of its original `this`. It has no default binding of `this` and that value of `this` is based on how it is called. The link attached by @VLAZ explain the same thing. How the value of `this` is determined

Comment: @user31782 and...so? It's still correct. And explained in the duplicates. If you *don't* want to focus on react or components, then [here is an even simpler example](https://jsbin.com/bameyotuye/1/edit?js,console) that demonstrates that `this` is not bound. I do not understand what *you* don't understand here. `this` is late-bound - at call time. Unless it's in an arrow function, which uses lexical binding. That's explained in the duplicates. The statement you quoted is correct.

Comment: @TusharShahi I understand this for the event listeners stuff, but my question is not about event listeners. I am going to delete that from my question and make it clear that I am asking about classes and their methods, not about event listeners.

Comment: ok ok, I think what react docs mean is this: *In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default, i.e. if those class methods are called without the context of their object*.

Comment: This is not specifically related to reactjs. It is about the very foundation of JavaScript: functions don't *belong* to a certain class/prototype, like you would expect in other languages. It is not even specific for `class`: it is the same principle for functions defined "old style" on a constructor's `prototype`, or functions defined as object properties in an object literal. It's all the same principle.

Comment: @trincot but most of the time we call object's function with an object like `obj.foo()`, we can't usually call `foo()`. For the most part functions/methods of a class are bound to their objects. It's just that when we use `bind` or `apply` that this binding changes. Or if the method happens to be returning another function, then that another function would get executed outside of the object context.

Comment: "*For the most part functions/methods of a class are bound to their objects.*" no, they *aren't*. That's what late binding is *and the very quote you wanted to discuss*. "*It's just that when we use bind or apply that this binding changes*" or ***EXTRAORDINARILY VERY COMMON*** when you pass a method as a reference when a callback is needed. This kind of problem is one of the highest asked about on SO in the JS-family tags. I don't get what you're trying to advocate for here - that behaviour *that is proven to you multiple times* does not exist?

Comment: @VLAZ WHat you mean by _when you pass a method as a reference_? I don't think we can pass references in js. I am not advocating anything, I have just asked a question to more knowledgeable people about what reactjs docs mean by _In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default_.

Comment: "*WHat you mean by when you pass a method as a reference?*" `.addEventListener("click", obj.foo)` which was my first example to you. And one of the most common types of problems. And explain *in depth* in [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484) which is [the fourth most frequent JS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?tab=Frequent) because we get a dozen or two a day of these where users did some variation of `functionThatTakesCallback(obj.someMethod)` and got the wrong value for `this`.

Comment: "*I have just asked a question to more knowledgeable people about what reactjs docs mean by In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default.*" which was explained rather thoroughly with supporting materials and examples. Only for you to turn around and say that it's not true. Hence my question - what are you advocating for? Because if you wanted knowledge, you've been supplied with it. If you're disputing it *in face of facts*, then that doesn't seem like asking for knowledge to me.

Comment: @VLAZ I don't think `.addEventListener("click", obj.foo)` is a pass by reference. js doesn't have this feature like other classical languages where you use `function(&reference)`

Comment: [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15886272)

Comment: Those answer don't seem to be legit, they don't have any documentation references to back them up. I think they are misusing the term `reference`.

Comment: The value of an object is its reference. Functions are objects. Ergo, passing `fn` as an argument, supplies the called function with the reference to `fn`. But since this all seems to be just you arguing against long-established, well-documented, facts about JS, that's the last of me. I feel I'm wasting my time having to explain and justify concepts and all I get is arguments that it's wrong to which I have to dig out more resources. I'm not here to have to argue facts exist.